# Error when trying to run STORM_TEST on yahoo streaming-benchmark

Tags: java, streaming, apache-kafka, apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

When I try to test STORM using yahoo streaming-benchmark I get these errors. I tried changing the port to 2080 instead of default port 2181 in ZooKeeper "zoo.cfg" file and kafka "server.properties". Still I get the same error. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance. :-)

```
2792 [main] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxnFactory - binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181
2796 [main] ERROR o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxnFactory - Thread Thread[main,5,main] died
java.lang.RuntimeException: No port is available to launch an inprocess zookeeper.
    at org.apache.storm.zookeeper$mk_inprocess_zookeeper$fn__2124$fn__2126.invoke(zookeeper.clj:223) ~[storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at org.apache.storm.zookeeper$mk_inprocess_zookeeper$fn__2124.invoke(zookeeper.clj:219) ~[storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at org.apache.storm.zookeeper$mk_inprocess_zookeeper.doInvoke(zookeeper.clj:217) ~[storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:439) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.storm.command.dev_zookeeper$_main.doInvoke(dev_zookeeper.clj:25) ~[storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:397) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:152) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.storm.command.dev_zookeeper.main(Unknown Source) ~[storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
Redis is already running...
WARNING: send already refers to: #'clojure.core/send in namespace: setup.core, being replaced by: #'clj-kafka.new.producer/send
{:redis-host localhost, :kakfa-brokers localhost:9092}
Writing campaigns data to Redis.
Error: Could not find or load main class .home.eranga.Software.kafka-0.10.0.1.config.server.properties
Unrecognized option: --create
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

---

Comment: I found the answer to the first ERROR
`java.lang.RuntimeException: No port is available to launch an inprocess zookeeper.`
This happens because ZooKeeper is already running before we begin testing the benchmark for Storm. So we first need to stop ZooKeeper, using the following commands on Terminal
`cd $zookeeper_dir-version/bin/` and then
`./zkServer.sh stop`

Comment: The reason for the second error `Error: Could not find or load main class .home.eranga.Software.kafka-0.10.0.1.config.server.properties` was that I was using the source version of kafka. What I should have used was the binary version of kafka. (Oops :-P Silly me)
So the solution was to download the binary version and set the path variables to that version. I hope this helps others :-)

Comment: Maybe mark your solution as an answer?

Comment: Hope this does it :-) Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is described in first and second comments by myself.